# Haskell programe fix

Tags: haskell

guys can you help me fix this code?

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

-- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

colors = [1,2,3,4,5]

--game :: [Integer] -> [Char]
game a = do 
      let black = test a color
          white = (test2 a color) - black
      let x = [a] ++ createScore black white
      show x

test [] [] = 0
test (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x == y then 1+test xs ys else 0+test xs ys

test2 a b = length (intersection a b)

intersection first second = [n | n <- first ,  isInfixOf [n] second]

createScore c b = [(take c (repeat 1) ++ take b (repeat 0))]

start = do 
      a <- getLine
      let b = map read $ words a
      --print b
      game b 
      start
```

I have problem with IO and nonIO functions. 
description of the program:

1. read data from line
2. convert data to List of int
3. call function game (which takes List of int like parametr)
4. make some calculation
5. print score
6. start again from 1

Problem is in function start and I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should add the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a few things that don't quite work with the code you've given us.

I'll work through the compile errors.

On first load we get a name error:

```
ex1.hs:10:26:
Not in scope: 'color'
Perhaps you meant 'colors' (line 6)
```

(and again at line 11)

Of course the compiler is correct and we just need to change the appropriate names to match.

Next we get the interesting one I assume you're referring to with regards to IO and non-IO functions:

```
ex1.hs:28:7:
Couldn't match type '[]' with 'IO'
Expected type: IO Char
  Actual type: String
In the return type of a call of 'game'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: game b
In the expression:
  do { a <- getLine;
       let b = map read $ words a;
       game b;
       start }
```

The error is your use of `game b` in the `IO` block.

The type annotation you have commented out over the function definition of `game` is actually correct -- it is `[Integer] -> [Char]`.

As such it's a pure function and we don't need to use the `do` notation to describe it like we would with something that deals with IO -- because you have used the notation here with an argument of a list, the `do` expression represents a computation in the context of a list, not an IO computation, so calling it from `start` has a type mismatch, it expects `IO`, but it has found `[]`.

We can start fixing it up by turning `game` into a pure function, using a `let-in` expression.

```
game :: [Integer] -> [Char]
game a = let black = test a colors
             white = (test2 a colors) - black
             x = [a] ++ createScore black white
         in show x
```

So now we have a function that returns the string of the input and it's score.

The compiler now gives the error `Expected type: IO Char, Actual type: [Char]`, this is because we are still trying to use a non-IO expression in the main `do` block.

We can fix this by actually printing the string to `stdout`, just using print, so your original

```
--print b
game b
```

can just be

```
print $ game b
```

At this point the program compiles!

Unfortunately it's still not quite right, when we run this and type in a list of integers like `1 2 3` we get the exception `ex1.hs:(14, 1)-(15,66): Non-exhaustive patterns in function test`.

This one comes down to your definition of `test` as:

```
test [] [] = 0
test (x:xs) (y:ys)
```

Doesn't account for the possibility of one list being empty -- because the check is always between the head elements of the lists probably the smallest change to fix this could just be:

```
test (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x == y then 1+test xs ys else 0+test xs ys
test _ _ = 0
```

And now the program compiles and executes. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for this helpful answer but i still get error message `ERROR - Cannot find "show" function for:
*** Expression : start
*** Of type    : IO a`

Comment: hey Alrick -- firstly, looks like you're using hugs, so sorry for quoting my ghci error messages at you. That error your getting is probably because you have `show start` somewhere in your code, hugs can't `show` that because the polymorphic type `IO a` is not a member of the `show` typeclass. That is, you have a type with an unknown parameter `a`, so how can hugs figure out what to print? For what it's worth, here is the complete text of the given code that will compile and run on my machine: https://gist.github.com/kjgorman/8e999820d45dfc2e2884

Comment: Thanks it works now. Hugs has problem with infinite recursion i fixed it by if, else statement

Answer (score 0):

`game` is (or should be) a pure function, so you need to call it with a function that returns an IO value in your `start` function, e. g. `print $ game b`. 
There is also no reason to use `do` notation there (you can because `[a]` is also a monad, but you don't take advantage of it in any way). You can just use `game a = show x` and replace the `let` statements with a `where` block (or use `let` ... `in`). 
`test` should be able to deal with the case of one list being empty and the other not, or you need to ensure that both lists are always the same size.